# I can not get sound on my headphones

Tags: sound

I am using Ubuntu 17.10. I play audio or video but sound is not going through the headphones.

I tested everything, my headphones are OK, Ubuntu recognizes my headphones and its microphone is working well. When I play something on internal speakers it works but when I put my headphones it gives no sound.

Comment: Please click in the sound indicator and make sure to explicitly select the headphones.

Comment: Thank You, but whenever I put my headphones my ubuntu selects headphones as output for sound I have checked this in settings-sounds and then choose a device for sound output. headphone is selected